# Truffle constant functions run out of gas, how to simulate a local node

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, react

I am new to solidity and web3. I am getting familiar with Truffle, testrpc and web3 1.x. I am also using React as a front end.

I know that functions that don't change the smart contract state can actually run for free if they are executed from a local node. I have a function that would be very costly to run, but I only plan to use it from a local node since it doesn't change the state of the smart contract and is declared as a constant function.

I have been trying to run some automated tests using truffle and I keep getting out of gas errors. So I also tried to run this from React and (not surprisingly) I have the same error.

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
myAbi = [...]
myAddress = "0x..."
var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myAbi, myAddress);

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    myContract.methods.myFunction().call().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
  }
  ...
}
```

> Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas

Is there a way to simulate a local node? I would like to know what causes this problem and what the workaround is. I am mostly interested in getting React to work but I hope there is a generic solution that would also solve this for truffle tests. Any references would also be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you running these automated tests in the private chain?
Does the address that you are using have enough Ether?

Comment: Even if the function does not modify the state it does use gas. The difference with a transaction is that the gas is not paid for. But still, the execution can run out of gas in the same way a transaction does. It would be helpful to see the solidity code to give you some help.

Comment: I am literally looping over a big mapping (1M entries) make it into an array and return it. I know this is not proper practice but since I though of it as being "free" I took this approach. Is this viable at all or is this something completely unacceptable and/or impossible in practice?

Comment: Try passing more gas to the call `myContract.methods.myFunction().call({ gas: 100000000 })`.